# Spliting rows into multiple rows and adding NA when needed

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have the following dataframe:

```
A      B       C       D       E       F       G      
1/2    3/4     4/5/6   7/8     9/10    11      12/13/14/15
```

And want to split to:

```
A      B       C       D       E       F       G      
1      3       4       7       9       11      12
2      4       5       8       10      NA      13   
NA     NA      6       NA      NA      NA      14
NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      15
```

Is there any compact way to do it?

I've tought about separating each column into a list, using something such as

```
 list_of_dfs
```

and for each df do:

```
 modified_dfs %>% separate_rows(colnames(each_df), sep = "/")
```

then doing a merge of all dataframes created in the process...

```
 merge(modified_dfs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more easier with `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, names(df1), sep = "/", "long")
```

-output

```
     A     B     C     D     E     F     G
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1:     1     3     4     7     9    11    12
2:     2     4     5     8    10    NA    13
3:    NA    NA     6    NA    NA    NA    14
4:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    15
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = "1/2", B = "3/4", C = "4/5/6", D = "7/8", 
    E = "9/10", F = 11L, G = "12/13/14/15"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: It works like a charm! I have tried cSplit(df1, colnames(df1), sep = "/", "long") which gave me a weird C error!